# Positional number representation

Tags: number-formats

There is a definition of integer representation:

> A positional representation for integers that uses the binary digits 0
>   and 1, in which the values represented by successive bits are
>   additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive integral
>   power of 2, except perhaps for the bit with the highest position.
>   (Adapted from the American National Dictionary for Information
>   Processing Systems.)

It is not clear to me. Could you give an example reflects that definition? In general, I don't understand what is the `successive integral power of 2` and what is the `succesive bits`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be nothing more than a description of the standard binary notation. List the bits in the string and below them, starting with 1 at the rightmost position and multiplying by 2 at each position to the left:
$$\begin{array}{lccccc}
\mathbf{bits:} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\mathbf{powers\ of\ 2:} & 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1\\
\mathbf{product:} & 16 & 8 & 0 & 2 & 0
\end{array}$$
then add the resulting products: $16 + 8 + 0 + 2 + 0=26$, as it should be, since $\mathtt{11010}_2=26$.

The `successive integral powers of 2` are just those that appear in the second line, right to left, and similarly `successive bits` are those in the first line, again reading from right to left. I must confess to being confused by the phrase `except perhaps for the bit in highest position`.

Comment: The bit in highest position might be used for sign. That is the likely reason for why it is `except`.